# Where's the Stack Exchange for Windows administrators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The Super User homepage says "for computer enthusiasts and power users".
https://superuser.com/

Ok, cool.

But, where do Windows admins and professionals ask questions?

I searched "Find a Stack Exchange community", but I only found Windows Phone:

[image: Search]

I also tried microsoft.stackexchange.com (since there exists an apple.stackexchange.com), but it wasn't found either.

[image: URL]

I also tried windows.stackexhange.com, just in case, and got "Couldn't find windows.stackexchange.com"

[image: URL]

Comment: It's not very helpful if you downvote, but don't explain why you downvoted. Then it just seems arbitrary.

Comment: The downvote button says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". If you get downvotes without comment; assume that's the reason.

Comment: There is a regularly reappearing "Ask Microsoft" initiative on the Area51. You could work on it, maybe the SE will start it. Also I helped them with some popular ;-) questions.

Comment: How do you look for the Redhat Stack Exchange?

Comment: One might ask, why doesn't searching for "Windows" in "Find a StackExchange community" bring up either ServerFault or SuperUser. Or why there's an apple.stackexchange.com, but no microsoft.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That assumes you're searching through the on topic segment of all the sites, not the name of the site as that search is for

Comment: For future reference, searching for "admin" would have found SF fairly easily in a much shorter list.

Comment: @random, "Windows" is a topic. Maybe i misunderstood what you're saying-- plz try to fix your grammar if possible. Thx.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, "admin" is so broad and general as to not be a logical first try.

Comment: But it's in your question. "Where do **Windows admins and professionals** […]?" Splitting each of those words out is only good searching practice. ("Professional" and "Windows" find nothing useful, certainly, but, as noted, "admin" does.)

Comment: How do you find the site to ask questions about Java programming?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, "linux" produces results. "apple" produces results. But "microsoft" does not, and "windows" only gives "windows phone". That's inconsistent search results. Linux and Apple have dedicated groups, but Windows and Microsoft do not. That's inconsistent community. Seems an a strong bias against Windows and Microsoft.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Professional system administrators of Windows systems can ask questions at Server Fault, where [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) is the #3 most common tag.

Be sure to read their [on-topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), because... sysadmins.

Comment: Thx much, @Gerry.

Comment: One might ask, why doesn't searching for "Windows" in "Find a StackExchange community" bring up *either* Server Fault *or* SuperUser. Or why there's an apple.stackexchange.com, but no windows.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user153505 - The search feature your using is searching the name of the SE community.  it is NOT searching what is or isn't on topic at a speciifc website.  So the reason both those communities do not show up, is neither of them have "Windows" in their name, so your using the "search for a community" feature expecting a result that isn't possible.  In the future I suggest just reading the help center of a community before asking a question there.

Comment: @user153505, if that search feature only accepts actual community names, and i do not happen to know that the two Windows groups are called "Server Fault" and "Super User", then to me that's a flawed search mechanism. "Server Fault" and "Super User" are colorful non-Microsoft-specific titles, and not reasonable to expect anyone to guess them out of thin air. "Windows" is not even in the popup description. It's practically obfuscation.